# What is the inverse of O(log n) time?

Tags: math, time-complexity

I'm doing some math, and today I learned that the inverse of a^n is log(n). I'm wondering if this applies to complexity. Is the inverse of superpolynomial time logarithmic time and vice versa?

I would think that the inverse of logarithmic time would be O(n^2) time.

Can you characterize the inverses of the common time complexities?

Cheers!

Comment: I can think about such definition: if you apply two algorithms, O(log n) and O(n^2) one after another (one upon another ? TBD), you get O(1) algorithm ( O(0) ? TBD).

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to define what you mean by inverse here. If you mean an inverse by composing two functions together with the linear function being the identity function, i.e. f(x)=x, then the inverse of f(x)=log x would be f(x)=10^x. However, one could define a multiplicative function inverse where the constant function f(x)=1 is the identity function, then the inverse of f(x)=x would be f(x)=1/x. While this is a bit complicated, it isn't that different than saying, "What is the inverse of 2?" and without stating an operation, this is quite difficult to answer. An additive inverse would be -2 while a multiplicative inverse would be 1/2 so there are different answers depending on which operator you want to use.

In composing functions, the key becomes what is the desired end result: Is it O(n) or O(1)? If the latter may be much more challenging in composing functions as I'm not sure if composing O(log n) with a O(1) would give you a constant in the end or if it doesn't negate the initial count. For example, consider doing a binary search for something with O(log n) time complexity and a basic print statement as something with O(1) time complexity and if you put these together, you'd still get O(log n) as there would still be log n calls within the composed function that prints a number each time going through the search.

Consider the idea of taking two different complexity functions and putting one inside the other, the overall complexity is likely to be the product of each. Consider a double for loop where each loop is O(n) complexity, the overall complexity is O(n) X O(n) = O(n^2) which would mean that in the case of finding something that cancels out the log n would be challenging as you'd have to find something with O(1/(log n)) which I'm not sure exists in reality.